# How do I start in C# a function that's async from a function that isn't?

Tags: c#

I have a function that isn't `async` and as a result I can't use `await`. In that function I call a function that's `async`.

My coworker suggested I use:

```
private void Foo()
{
   var _ = BarAsync();
}
```

This way however has the disadvantage that I don't get notified when the function throws errors. Is there a better way to call the function? I don't care whether or not the function gets executed asyncronly.

Comment: You can synchronously block on it using `Wait` -> `BarAsync().Wait();`

Comment: I'm trying to get the MS docs updated with this information. Go vote on this: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/7995

Comment: @AlexanderDerck : Does that allow me to receive Expection that get throw within the function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = BarAsync()?.Result;
```

Or

```
var runningTask = BarAsync();
runningTask.Wait();
var result = runningTask?.Result;
```

Comment: this is a very bad idea in the general case - and can even cause hard deadlocks; the **only** time you should *ever* access `.Result` is if you have checked and you *know* that it has completed

Comment: @Liam both can :)